# Hide port in address bar when run NodeJS locally on Windows

Tags: node.js

As we know, when we run NodeJS on hosting server and want to hide port like `:3000` from the browser address bar, we can set up `ngnix` or use in `.htaccess` the rules like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

But what about running NodeJS locally on Windows? Is it possible to hide the port in the browser address bar in this case? I mean without additional server

ps. I run Windows binary 64-bit version of NodeJS on Windows 7

Comment: You can't. The nginx rewrite rule you mentioned is just serving your file from localhost:3000 at localhost:80 (or 443) (the default http/https port number which can be omitted). That's not exactly "hiding ports". That's nginx serving at the front while remapping the resource for incoming requests.

Comment: If you want to "hide" the ports, you need to run your node js server at default http/https ports, which requires the program run in sudo. Such way is not recommended and you should use with a web server service like nginx, apache, etc. in the front instead if you're in production.

Comment: Oh, it turns out when we run NodeJS locally it's enough to specify port 80 in my JS file to "hide" the port from the address bar. Do you mean "such way is not recommended" when we run NodeJS locally or on hosting?

Comment: It depends on your context. It normally requires "Administrator's privilege"(in windows) or sudo(in bsd) in order to bind your application at 80/443 port. If your server application runs in a sudo mode to use these ports(which can modify system settings etc.), your system will become vulnerable in terms of security.

Comment: I've just specified port 80 in my JS file, run it under the standard user account without "Administrator's privilege" and now there is no need to add a port in the address bar. It seems every third-part app based on NodeJS can harm OS regardless of the user mode since it has the access to file system.

Comment: I'm no expert on windows. Maybe that works in windows and it may have its own security problems. Or maybe you user account is already an administrator or the privilege control was disabled. I don't understand why it doesn't ask for the privilege. It definitely should do. And you'll of course need privilege in order to access files in for example \windows or \program files. Normal file system access cannot easily harm the system(it can, for sure). However it's possible/easier with the root privileges.

Comment: And root privilege does not only mean file system access. It means much more. You can do anything with your system if you have root privilege.